# WCF Rest Service With Multiple Contracts

Tags: wcf-rest

I am developing a WCF Rest Service that will implement multiple contracts (at current 2).  I deployed the solution to IIS under the default web site. On accessing the uri:

```
http://localhost/wcfrestsample/myservices/service1/customers:
```

I get following invalid operation exception:

> Service 'MyService' implements multiple ServiceContract types, and no endpoints are defined in the configuration file. WebServiceHost can set up default endpoints, but only if the service implements only a single ServiceContract. Either change the service to only implement a single ServiceContract, or else define endpoints for the service explicitly in the configuration file.

Below is the code details:

```
namespace WcfRestServiceSample
{
    //Data Items...

    public class Customer
    {
        public String Address { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public String EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }
        public Double Salary { get; set; }
    }

    //Service Contracts...

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService1
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "customers")]
        IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers();
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService2
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "employees")]
        IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees();
    }

    //Service Implementation...

    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class MyService : IMyService1, IMyService2
    {
        public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
            return new List<Customer>
            {
                new Customer{ Address = "customer 1 address", Name = "Customer 1" },
                new Customer{ Address = "customer 2 address", Name = "Customer 2" }
            };
        }

        public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            return new List<Employee>
            {
                new Employee{ EmployeeNumber = "Employee 1", JoiningDate = new DateTime(1995, 5, 5), Salary = 5555.55 },
                new Employee{ EmployeeNumber = "Employee 2", JoiningDate = new DateTime(1998, 8, 8), Salary = 8888.88 }
            };
        }
    }

    //The Global.asax

    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("MyServices", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MyService)));
        }
    }
}
```

The contents of the config file are as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="MyService">
        <endpoint address="service1" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfRestServiceSample.IMyService1" />
        <endpoint address="service2" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfRestServiceSample.IMyService2" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <!-- 
            Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
            via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
        -->
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add 
        name="UrlRoutingModule" 
        type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

**Am I missing something?**

Comment: Did you find a solution, yet? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

when working with multiple contracts, you cant use a base address at all. Even if the relative address of the endpoint would create unique URIs for each endpoint. Its stupid like that.
Try mentioning the whole address in the endpoint. I think it will work then.

i.e. make your endpoint like :

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost/wcfrestsample/myservices/service1" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfRestServiceSample.IMyService1" />
<endpoint address="http://localhost/wcfrestsample/myservices/service2" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfRestServiceSample.IMyService2" />
```